# infinite type inferred due to pattern variable

Tags: purescript

Using a pattern variable that names an entire case expression makes the difference between compiling correctly and the error "An infinite type was inferred for an expression". The following compiles correctly:

```
m = case Left "anything" of
  e@(Left err) -> Left err
  (Right f) -> case lookup "key" f of
    Nothing -> Left "something else"
    (Just x) -> Right x
```

However, if we use the pattern variable e (substituting e for "Left err", functionally equivalent), the compiler flags an error:

```
m = case Left "anything" of
  e@(Left err) -> e
  (Right f) -> case lookup "key" f of
    Nothing -> Left "something else"
    (Just x) -> Right x
```

"An infinite type was inferred for an expression: StrMap t1 while trying to match type t1 with type StrMap t1 while checking that expression case ((lookup "key") f) ...

I understand that matching StrMap t1 with t1 is problematic. I do not understand why this happens. Also, in my original code the message did not refer to infinite types at all. Here is the relevant extract:

```
retrieveDomeinResourceDefinition :: forall e.
  ResourceId
  -> Namespace
  -> (AsyncDomeinFile e (Either String PropDefs))
retrieveDomeinResourceDefinition id ns = do
  df <- retrieveDomeinFile (namespaceToDomeinFileName ns)
  case df of
    e@(Left err) -> pure $ e
    (Right f) -> case lookup id f of
      Nothing -> pure $ Left ("retrieveDomeinResourceDefinition: cannot find definition of " <> id <> " in DomeinFile for " <> ns)
      (Just propDefs) -> pure (Right propDefs)

retrieveDomeinFile :: forall e. Namespace -> AsyncDomeinFile e (Either String DomeinFile)

newtype PropDefs = PropDefs (StrMap Json)
```

Now here the compiler tells me: "Could not match type: PropDefs with type StrMap PropDefs..." It appears as if the compiler does not notice the lookup expression. In fact, when I replace "pure (Right propDefs)" with "pure (Right f)", the error goes away (and another appears on the line binding df, which I understand).

Now I write this up I notice the similarity between 'trying to match type t1 with type StrMap t1' and 'could not match type: PropDefs with StrMap PropDefs'. Still, I don't see why using e introduces this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the value from a pattern match that way may be functionally equivalent, but the types are not - the type system doesn't have the evidence that the type variable for the `Right` can be ignored.

Using the types in your second example - when you pattern match `e@(Left err)`, the type of `e` will be `Either String DomeinFile` - but you want an `Either String PropDefs`. The pattern match does not "free up" the type variable on the right, which is why you have to reconstruct the `Left` with the error again.

Comment: I see. I mistakenly thought the cases split over the type union (each case another member of the union), but the type of each case is the entire union.